# PTPP MS-VPN just stopped working, giving out error 807

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, windows-sbs-2011

Today our VPN stopped accepting connections, the clients are returning error 807. There is nothing in the logs on the server that pertain to VPN failing, or that clients have even attempted to connect today. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

If you need more information, please let me know. The server is running Windows SBS 2011 Essentials, though all other issues I've had with the server have been able to be fixed using suggestions meant for Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rule out the router, firewall, and internet connection by establishing a VPN connection to the server from a LAN connected machine.
2. If you're unable to establish a VPN connection to the server from a LAN connected machine (meaning you get the same error), then reboot the server.
3. Proceed as warranted based on the result of step 2.

Comment: I wasn't able to get a connection locally, so I made a lot of people very angry :) and rebooted the server. Everything works again, but strange that restarting the service had no effect, warranting the reboot